# Can't redirect laravel to root folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I installed laravel on folder `laravel` in `www` and it works fine. I wanted to make it work on `root`, so I moved all folders except `public` into `www/laravel` and `public` folder content in `www` and I modified 2 lines in `index.php` in `www` to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and in `laravel/bootstrap/paths.php`, I modified one line to:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html'
```

but when I try access localhost, I get this error:

> ( ! ) Warning: require(C:\wamp\www/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 21
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed
>   opening required 'C:\wamp\www/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 21

How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the file permission?

Answer (score 0):

it seem to work on fine in `Laravel 5`

move `public/index.php` to rood directory and edit 2 line

line 21 `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

to `require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

and

line 35 `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: try to copy `.htaccess` and `index.php` from `public` folder to `root` directory and edit 2 line same answer above

Comment: i did that but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Download the original laravel folder and replace those files and index

Comment: i did that and get same problem